# how to create div inside fieldset in rails simple form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I got simple form with associated checkboxes. And i need to style that checkboxes with twitter bootstrap class "col-md-4" which render that checkboxes in 3 columns. but it needs 'row' class on a parent element, which is fieldset. when I assign that class to fieldset, it doesn't work. but if I change parent element to div in browser devtool, it works great.
Is any way I can create another div inside fieldset, which will be a parent element for all my checkboxes divs? or any other way to solve my problem?

```
_form.slim
=simple_form_for @test_run do |f|
  =f.error_notification
  =f.association :test_cases, as: :check_boxes, collection: ::TestCase.all, include_hidden: false, :item_wrapper_class => 'col-md-4'
  =f.input :video, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Record video?'
  =f.submit


html
<fieldset class="form-group check_boxes required test_run_test_cases">
  <legend class="col-form-label pt-0">Test cases <abbr title="required">*</abbr></legend>
  <div class="col-md-4">checkbox</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">checkbox</div>
  .
  .
  .
</fieldset>
```

and i need something like this

```
<fieldset class="form-group check_boxes required test_run_test_cases">
  <div class="row">
    <legend class="col-form-label pt-0">Test cases <abbr title="required">*</abbr></legend>
    <div class="col-md-4">checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">checkbox</div>
    .
    .
    .
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Look like you need a custom input. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605976/simple-form-collection-wrapper-radios-buttons-double-encapsulation-of-items

Answer (score 1):

For me the quickest solution was to actually change the default wrapper tag in:

```
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb
config.collection_wrapper_tag = :div
```

This will create a div around the checkboxes or radio buttons. 
You can then assign a class to this div by using `collection_wrapper_class` in the simple form input. For your case it would be

```
=f.input :video, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Record video?', collection_wrapper_class: 'some-class'
```